# Exponents with power 2019 mod 144

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Problem: What is the remainder when $11^{2019}+13^{2019}$ is divided by $144$?

I saw that $$11^{2019}+13^{2019} \equiv (-1)^{2019}+(1)^{2019} \equiv 0 \pmod{12},$$
but I don't now how to proceed from here. Can you help me?

Comment: $12^2=0\pmod{144}$ and use binomial with $11=12-1,13=12+1$. More generally see hensel lifting

Comment: how does $12^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{144}$ imply the result?

Comment: $(12+1)^n=\binom{12}01+\binom{12}112+\binom{12}212^2+\dots$ from here it should be clear most terms in the binomial expansion is just 0

Comment: @Ariana ig it will be $\binom{n}01+\binom{n}112+\binom{n}212^2+\dots$

Comment: @ChemistryLover oops mb yea

Answer (score 0):

Euler $\phi(144)=\phi(16)*\phi(9)=8*6=48$. $2019\equiv 3 \mod 48$, so your sum is $11^3+13^3 \mod 144$. $11^3+13^3\equiv 72 \mod 144$. Answer $72$.

Comment: applying $(x-1)^3+(x+1)^3=2x^3+6x$ with $x=12$ shows that $11^3+13^3\equiv6\cdot12\bmod144$

Comment: For me it is easier to just compute $11^3=1331 \equiv 35  \mod 144$, $13^3=2197\equiv 37 \mod 144$, $35+37=72$

Answer (score -1):

The theorem is that

$$
a^c\equiv (a-kb)^c\quad(\bmod b)
$$

where $a, b, c, k\in\mathbb{N}$, you can use the Binomial theorem to prove this.

Answer (score -1):

$11^{2019}=(12-1)^{2019}=\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{2019}\binom{2019}{r}12^r(-1)^{2019-r}=\displaystyle\sum_{r=2}^{2019}\binom{2019}{r}12^r(-1)^{2019-r}-\binom{2019}{0}+\binom{2019}{1}12$.
$\displaystyle\sum_{r=2}^{2019}\binom{2019}{r}12^r(-1)^{2019-r}$ is divisible by $12^2$. Therefore$$11^{2019}\equiv{-\binom{2019}{0}+\binom{2019}{1}12}\mod 144\equiv35\mod144$$

Similarly, $13^{2019}=(12+1)^{2019}=\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{2019}\binom{2019}{r}12^r=\displaystyle\sum_{r=2}^{2019}\binom{2019}{r}12^r+\binom{2019}{0}+\binom{2019}{1}12$.

$\displaystyle\sum_{r=2}^{2019}\binom{2019}{r}12^r$ is divisible by $12^2$. Therefore$$13^{2019}\equiv{\binom{2019}{0}+\binom{2019}{1}12}\mod 144\equiv37\mod144$$

Therefore, $$11^{2019}+13^{2019}\equiv35+37\mod 144\equiv72\mod 144$$

I hope you have no problem with [Binomial Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).